# Error fetching the right path from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to react native i'm working on fetching the list from firebase. But i'm stuck at giving paths to the object. i don't known how to give path to the event id which is shown in fig.
[image]

Here is the code to which i want to give the right path. Any help will be appreciated.

```
firebase.database().ref('/events').child('/friends').once('value').then((snapshot) =>{
    let data = snapshot.val();
    let items = object.values(data);
    allUserList.push(items);
    this.setState({allFriendList: allFriendList});

}
```

I have multiple keys see the image
[image]

Here is the code of the flatlist in which i want to show the friend list

```
<FlatList style={{}} keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'always'}
data={this.state.allFriendList}
ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.goToNextScreen(item)}>
        <View style={{
                flexDirection: 'row', paddingBottom: 5, paddingTop: 5,
                justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'
            }}>
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code meant to do? Is it meant to show a list of events? Or is it meant to show the list of friends of one event? In the latter case, do you know the key of the event you want to show the friends list of?

Comment: Yes I know the key of the event for friend list i have done evething the only thing where i'm stuck is i'm not able to set correct path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the list of friends for a certain event, and you know the key of that event, you can do something like:

```
let eventKey = '-LRuFQAsleScaEK2MqXu';
let eventRef = firebase.database().ref('events').child(eventKey);
eventRef.child('friends').once('value').then((snapshot) =>{
  let allFriendList = [];
  snapshot.forEach((friendSnapshot) => {
    let data = friendSnapshot.val();
    allUserList.push(data);
  });
  this.setState({allFriendList: allFriendList});
});
```

Some of the changes:

- This code only listens for the specific path `/events/-LRuFQAsleScaEK2MqXu/friends`. In fact, it could have used that path to listen to, i.e. firebase.database().ref('/events/-LRuFQAsleScaEK2MqXu/friends').once('value'...`
- The `snapshot` we get from this contains multiple friends, so we loop over them with `snapshot.forEach()`.
- Once we've added all friends to the list, we call `setState` to inform React of them.

---

In the comments you indicate you want all friends lists combined, which you can do with:

```
let eventsRef = firebase.database().ref('events');
eventRef.once('value').then((snapshot) =>{
  let allFriendList = [];
  snapshot.forEach((eventSnapshot) => {
    eventSnapshot.child('friends').forEach((friendSnapshot) => {
      let data = friendSnapshot.val();
      allUserList.push(data);
    });
  });
  this.setState({allFriendList: allFriendList});
});
```

But I **highly** recommend changing/augmenting your data model for this use-case. This code may work, but reads way more data than is needed. It also may be reading duplicate friends, if the same friend is present in more events. If you want a global list of friends, I'd store precisely that in the database: a list of users, with possibly the event IDs of the events they're friends with.

Comment: yes, that's right but i don't want for a specific user. for a particular user i have done.

Comment: in the  image i have shown that friend list is present. it is there for every key not for particular key

Comment: This was precisely why I asked if you know the key of the event you want to show. I updated my answer to show the other use-case too.

Comment: i implemented this code i'm getting error in  my mobile screen

Comment: Error: Refrence.child failed: first argument was an invalid path = "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".","#","$","[" or "]"

Comment: That error means you're passing a variable without a value into `child(...)`. I don't see anywhere in the code I posted where I do that, so am not sure where that would come from.

Comment: hello,i have resolved the issue. But i can't see anything in flatlist i have edited the question and added the code of flatlist, can u plzz check where is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do the full path in the ref:

```
firebase.database().ref('/events/friends/whatever-key')
    .once('value').then((snapshot) =>{
        /// Whatever code
    });
```

Comment: I have multiple key

Comment: plzz see the image i have added

Comment: I think you're looking for snapshot.key

Answer (score 0):

Personal preference, using the `[key]` approach works well for custom key names.

For instance,  `data.[key].name` will yield your results if you know the key.

If you don't know that key (`LRjSl...`) you can iterate over the `friends` object:

```
for (var key in data) {
    data[key].name //will be Shabnam
}
```